# Option depends on global settings specified elsewhere - how do I make this clear?

Tags: usability, disable

I've got a checkbox option 'show feature', that a client can enable or disable. This is an individual setting for each instance.

However, each instance depends on the global settings, which determine WHO sees this feature - 'no-one', 'anyone', 'registered users' or 'admins'.

My concern is that people will tick 'show feature', while having the global setting set to, for example, 'registered users', and then not know why it's not visible for everyone.

My attempt was to do something like this:

```
[] Show Feature
This setting relies on the global <feature settings>. (link)
```

or maybe

```
[] Show Feature
This setting relies on the global <feature settings>. (link)
Feature can currently be seen by *all users*.
Feature can currently be actioned by *admins only*.
```

But it's so much text that I think users will skip over it.

Another consideration is greying out the checkbox. This could happen when the feature is set to visible for 'none'. But it doesn't solve any problems for other global settings.

Comment: If changing it has no effect because of a global setting, disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either completely hide "[x] Show Features" locally for user roles not permitted of that operation.

if you still need to show it, you can do as illustrated

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZFmVo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I need to show it as it's dependant on a user-set global setting, not a user role. I've gone with something similar to your alternative solution, I'll review it after some feedback and testing.